# Error when trying to view catalog products in backend - Invalid attribute type

Tags: magento-1.8, product

I'm getting an error when I try to go to Catalog -> Manage Products in the backend. I'm using Magento ver 1.8.1.0.

I think I may have screwed up the database when I was trying to import some products. I'm wondering how I can make it go back to normal.  I've tried removing all products using [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11855267) but I still get the same error.

```
Invalid attribute type

#0 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php(652): Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', 'Invalid attribu...')
#1 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product/Grid.php(119): Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Collection_Abstract->joinAttribute('status', 'catalog_product...', 'entity_id', NULL, 'inner')
#2 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(626): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product_Grid->_prepareCollection()
#3 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Grid.php(632): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_prepareGrid()
#4 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(918): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid->_beforeToHtml()
#5 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#6 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('grid', true)
#7 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Catalog/Product.php(79): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('grid')
#8 /usr/share/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/catalog/product.phtml(46): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Catalog_Product->getGridHtml()
#9 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/usr/share/mage...')
#10 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#11 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#12 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#13 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Widget/Container.php(308): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#14 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Container->_toHtml()
#15 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Text/List.php(43): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#16 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Core_Block_Text_List->_toHtml()
#17 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(637): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#18 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(581): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->_getChildHtml('content', true)
#19 /usr/share/magento/app/design/adminhtml/default/default/template/page.phtml(74): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->getChildHtml('content')
#20 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(241): include('/usr/share/mage...')
#21 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(272): Mage_Core_Block_Template->fetchView('adminhtml/defau...')
#22 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Template.php(286): Mage_Core_Block_Template->renderView()
#23 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/Block/Template.php(81): Mage_Core_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#24 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Block/Abstract.php(919): Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Template->_toHtml()
#25 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/Layout.php(555): Mage_Core_Block_Abstract->toHtml()
#26 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(390): Mage_Core_Model_Layout->getOutput()
#27 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Adminhtml/controllers/Catalog/ProductController.php(180): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->renderLayout()
#28 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Action.php(418): Mage_Adminhtml_Catalog_ProductController->indexAction()
#29 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Router/Standard.php(250): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Action->dispatch('index')
#30 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Controller/Varien/Front.php(172): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Router_Standard->match(Object(Mage_Core_Controller_Request_Http))
#31 /usr/share/magento/app/code/core/Mage/Core/Model/App.php(354): Mage_Core_Controller_Varien_Front->dispatch()
#32 /usr/share/magento/app/Mage.php(684): Mage_Core_Model_App->run(Array)
#33 /usr/share/magento/index.php(87): Mage::run('', 'store')
#34 {main}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have XDebug then this would be an easy one to troubleshoot.  I'm assuming you don't or you wouldn't be asking your question.

One way you could possibly find out which attribute is causing the problem involves adding a Mage::log() entry in a core file.

*Note to everyone else reading this: I know this isn't the "right" way to do it but if someone doesn't have a IDE and debugger then this is the best I can think of under the circumstances.*

In `app/code/core/Mage/Eav/Model/Entity/Collection/Abstract.php` it's hitting an exception indicating that an attribute is invalid.

```
    // validate attribute
    if (is_string($attribute)) {
        $attribute = $entity->getAttribute($attribute);
    }
    if (!$attribute) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', Mage::helper('eav')->__('Invalid attribute type'));
    }
```

Just to determine exactly which attribute this is having a problem with, you should turn on the `system.log` and add a line in that file temporarily.

In that file around line 652, add the following code:

```
    // validate attribute

    Mage::log("Attribute: " . $attribute); // <-- new line

    if (is_string($attribute)) {
        $attribute = $entity->getAttribute($attribute);
    }
    if (!$attribute) {
        throw Mage::exception('Mage_Eav', Mage::helper('eav')->__('Invalid attribute type'));
    }
```

Go to your admin and open `Manage Products`. When you get the Exception message, go to `var/log/system.log` and look for the last entry that has `Attribute:` in it.

After your determine the attribute name that it has a problem with, undo the core hack.  Go to "Manage Attributes" to see if that attribute is listed.  If so, then delete it from there and re-index your site.

Comment: Thanks for your help! I'll definitely look into setting up XDebug to make debugging easier. The system.log file says: DEBUG (7): Attribute: status. However, I don't see that attribute listed under Manage Attributes. Is there an easy way to delete all attributes and restore to the default ones?

Comment: You don't see "status" in your Attributes?

Comment: If you followed the direct SQL delete advice in that other answer then you may have inadvertently corrupted your install.  If you're missing status then you may be missing other system attributes. Do you have any orders or customers in the system?  How big of a loss of time would it be if you just re-installed from scratch? :)

Comment: It seems to me you removed the EAV attribute, `status`. You can quickly check by going into the `eav_attribute` table or the admin's attribute seciton and look for `status` to verify.

Comment: @laketuna, yes that was already mentioned above.

Comment: @seanbreeden, OP never confirmed. Getting back to OP's comment, there is no easy way to remove and install all attributes back. I recommend a fresh install as seanbreeden said or attempt to create an attribute called `status` and make it into a system attribute manually in the table.

Comment: @laketuna:  "Attribute: status. However, I don't see that attribute listed under Manage Attributes." from above

Comment: Thanks for your help. I ended up starting over with a new database. This time I will be sure to make frequent backups.